# can't access to second character of a char * array

Tags: c

I've written this c code:

```
void main(){
    char *a[3] = {"slm", "boro", "dige"};
    printf("%s\n", *a);
    printf("%s\n", *(a+1));

    printf("%c\n", *a[1]);      //3
    printf("%c\n", *(a+1)[1]);  //4

    printf("%s\n", a[0]);
    printf("%s\n", a[1]);

    printf("%c\n", a[0][1]);    //1
    printf("%c\n", a[1][1]);    //2
}
```

In 1 and 2 I can print second character of "slm" and "boro"
but in 3 and 4 I tried to do same thing by pointer based method but it gives me first character of "boro" and "dige"

What can I do?

Comment: `*X` means `X[0]` , so `*a[1]` is `a[1][0]` , and `*(a+1)[1]` is `a[2][0]`. You could try `(*a)[1]` and `(*(a+1))[1]`

Comment: please tell me why (*a)[1] works ? I can't understand difference of this structure and what I've written above

Comment: Like M.M says.. "You could try (*a)[1] and (*(a+1))[1]"

Comment: I knew it worked but I can't understand difference of pointer to array and array to pointer

Comment: Ahh you've changed your comment. It works because you are taking your pointer to your 0th index of your array and putting parentheses around it to keep it that way. Otherwise, you are going to point to your 1st index with your method  `*(a+1)` .

Comment: I should say the reason it points to the 1st doing it your way, is because you put a+1 in parentheses which means it has precedence and is evaluated first before your `*`. You understand better?

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main(){
    char *a[3] = {"slm", "boro", "dige"};
    printf("%c\n", *a[1]);    // From pointer a, take what is in index 1 ("boro") and derreference it ("boro"[0] = 'b'), print it as a char ('b')
    printf("%c\n", (*a)[1]);  // From pointer a, derreference it (a[0] = "slm") and take what is in index 1 ("slm"[1] = 'l'), print it as a char ('l')

    printf("%c\n", *(a+1)[1]);    // From pointer a, add 1, take what is in index 1 ("dige") and derreference it ("dige"[0] = 'd'), print it as a char ('d')
    printf("%c\n", (*(a+1))[1]);  // From pointer a add 1 and derreference it ((a+1)[0] = "boro"),  and take what is in index 1 ("boro"[1] = 'o'), print it as a char ('o')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`*(a+1)` is actually `a[1]`, in 3) and 4)

```
printf("%c\n", *a[1]);      //3  is **(a+1)
printf("%c\n", *(a+1)[1]);  //4  is **(a+1+1)
```

In 3) `*(a+1)` gives you the 2nd string, `**(a+1)` its first char
In 4) same, for 2nd string

because `[` has more precedence than `*`. Instead

```
printf("%c\n", (*a)[1]);      //3 or a[0][1] ==> 's'
printf("%c\n", (*(a+1))[1]);  //4 or a[1][1] ==> 'o'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want an approach that uses just pointer arithmetic (without any indexing):

```
printf("%c\n", *(*a+1));     //3
printf("%c\n", *(*(a+1)+1)); //4
```

Explanation:

- `a` is an array of 3 `char` pointers.
- `*a` is the first `char` pointer in the array, and it points to the first `char` in "slm".
- `*a+1` points to the second `char` in "slm".
- `*(*a+1)` gets the second `char` in "slm".
- `printf("%c\n", *(*a+1))` prints the second `char` in "slm".
- `*(a+1)` is the second `char` pointer in the array, and it points to the first `char` in "boro".
- `*(a+1)+1` points to the second `char` in "boro".
- `*(*(a+1)+1)` gets the second `char` in "boro".
- `printf("%c\n", *(*(a+1)+1))` prints the second `char` in "boro".